# How to specify PostGIS geography value in a composite type literal?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a custom composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE place AS (
    name text,
    location geography(point, 4326)
);
```

I want to create a value of that type using a literal:

```
SELECT $$("name", "ST_GeogFromText('POINT(121.560800 29.901200)')")$$::place;
```

This fails with:

```
HINT:  "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
```

But this executes just fine:

```
SELECT ST_GeogFromText('POINT(121.560800 29.901200)');
```

I wonder what's the correct way to specify PostGIS geography value in a composite type literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to push a function call `ST_GeogFromText` into a text string. This will not be allowed, as it creates a possibility for SQL injection.

In second call you need ST_GeogFromText to mark the type of input. For a composite type, you did that already in type definition, so you can skip that part:

```
[local] gis@gis=# SELECT $$("name", "POINT(121.560800 29.901200)")$$::place;
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                           place                           │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ (name,0101000020E610000032E6AE25E4635E40BB270F0BB5E63D40) │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
Time: 0,208 ms
```

Another option would be to use non-literal form, which allows function calls:

```
[local] gis@gis=# SELECT ('name', ST_GeogFromText('POINT(121.560800 29.901200)'))::place;;
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                            row                            │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ (name,0101000020E610000032E6AE25E4635E40BB270F0BB5E63D40) │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

Time: 5,004 ms
```